# Why does OR have a short URL whereas MM has a long one?

Tags: support, sponsorship-and-advertising, stackexchange, other-se-sites, related-stack-exchange-sites

Operations Research has a short and succinct, beautiful URL: https://**or**.stackexchange.com/ 
Matter Modelling has a long and bulky URL which might even look like a spam site when we try to recruit experts to join the site via email: https://**mattermodeling**.stackexchange.com/

Is it because we're 4 characters shorter?

```
Operations Research
Matter Modeling
```

it would be nice if we could get matter.stackexchange.com or mm.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Does this depend on us?

Comment: @Camps it's a question for the SE staff :)